# library and its functions check

Tags: r

i have developed few packages (lets say 100 packages an example)

so i have to perform below validations

```
1. check whether package exists or not
    a) if package exists then load it
    b) if package does not exists, throw an error

2. check whether package contains the given function
    a) if function exists, call it
    b) if function does not exists, throw an error
```

so i have below code (which got wrapped as plumber APIs)

```
myPackageName='students'
tryCatch(library(myPackageName, character.only=TRUE),
         error = function(e){
           return("Given Package Does not Exists.!")
         }
)

functionName1 = 'records'
id1= ''
tryCatch((get(functionName1)(id1)),
         error = function(f){
           return('Given Function Does not Exists in ')
         }
)
```

the successful scenario is working fine. i mean when i give correct package names, function names.

but when i give wrong package or function names, the respective error functions not working (i mean exception/error block not getting executed)

Q1. can some please help me if there is an simplest way to do this.?

Q2. Let say i have a package called `teachers` and it contains 100 functions and few of them are below

```
a) teach(a,b,c)

b) teach(a,b)

c) teach(a)
```

so how to check whether the given function with arguments exists in package or not.?

Comment: I was in the process of answering this the last time when you deleted your question ...

Comment: @BenBolker i apologies, i deleted it. because i felt that the question was not having enough information

Comment: (1) Your Q2 is not clear. Technically, you can't have multiple functions called `teach` in the same namespace. Do you have a polymorphic S4 method and you're trying to test whether different signatures exist?  (2) It's best to try to ask a single, focused question in each SO post; you might consider posting Q2 as a separate question. (If you do have a polymorphic S4 method I'm probably going to give up; after 20 years I still can't really get my head around S4 properly ...)

Comment: @BenBolker thanks for the information, i'm completely new to R world. i dont know about S4. can you please help me with any examples/study guide for these things please

Comment: @user2587669 if you're just beginning in R, it seems very unlikely you need to worry about S4 at the moment. R doesn't have native function overloading with different signatures, but S4 is an object-oriented system which has been incorporated into R and does allow such things. However, such functions are not idiomatic R and are extremely rare in production code. My guess is that just testing functions exist will be good enough for your project.

Comment: @AllanCameron, while I agree completely with the spirit of your post, I would quibble with "not idiomatic R" ... some people (not including me) do use S4 classes very effectively, and they have been part of R for decades ...

Comment: @BenBolker I meant specifically that method selection according to signature isn't idiomatic, in the sense that  function selection according to the _number_ of passed arguments violates the principle of least astonishment. I don't mean that S4 itself isn't idiomatic, and would never try to argue that it can't be used effectively.  Sorry I wasn't clearer on that point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you just do:

```
if(!(myPackageName %in% installed.packages())) stop("Package not installed")
library(myPackageName, character.only = TRUE)
if(!(functionName1 %in% ls(paste0("package:", myPackageName))) stop("Function not found")
get(functionName1)(id1))
```

Comment: there can be overloaded functions something like 1) sum(a,b)     2) sum(a,b,c) then how to perform function existence in a package

Comment: I don't understand your comment, can you please clarify?  If this is an additional criterion to your question, could you please edit your question to add it?

Comment: @user2587669 the third line checks whether the function exists in the package without having to call the function. The last line attempts to run it because you said that's what you wanted to do. If you run the first three lines without an error, the package is installed and the function exists.

Comment: @AllanCameron question edited, look at Q2 (Question 2)

Comment: @user2587669 a single package can't contain overloaded functions like that. If you want to know the names of the parameters as a character vector you can do: `names(formals(get(functionName1)))`

Comment: @AllanCameron then how to check the functionName1 with arguments

Comment: @user2587669 what do you mean check it? Do you mean you want to test its output with specific inputs you have, or just check it does _anything_?

Comment: @AllanCameron let say i want to check whether teach(a,b,c) exists in teachers package or not .how can i do it.?  this code only checks whether function exists in package or not                     if(!(functionName1 %in% ls(paste0("package:", myPackageName))) stop("Function not found")          this code does not check with arguments

Comment: @user2587669 like I said, if you do `names(formals(get("teach")))` it will tell you the names of the arguments that `teach` accepts. There are not different versions of `teach` that take different arguments. R doesn't work like that. A function inside a package has a list of arguments (some of which may be optional) but there can only one function called `teach` inside `teachers`. If you write a function like this: `teach <- function(a, b, c) {return(a+b+c)]` and then write `teach <- function(a){ return(a)}`, the first function is just overwritten and doesn't exist any more.

Answer (score 2):

In general, I would suggest checking for the existence etc. and throwing an error if necessary rather than trying the operation and catching the error if thrown.

> 1. check whether package exists or not
>      a) if package exists then load it
>      b) if package does not exists, throw an error

I would suggest

```
if (!require(pkgname, character.only=TRUE, quietly=TRUE)) {
     stop(sprintf("package %s is not installed", pkgname))
}
```

> 2. check whether package contains the given function
>      a) if function exists, call it
>      b) if function does not exists, throw an error

```
pkgpos <- paste0("package:",pkgname)
if (!funname %in% ls(pos=pkgpos)) {
    stop(sprintf("can't find function %s in package %s", funname, pkgname))
}
fn <- get(funname, pos=pkgpos)
fn(id1)
```

This code does **not** check if `funname` is actually a function ...

Comment: That's a very good point Ben. There may be data objects or environments in the package namespace, so the code probably needs an `is.function` check too. I hadn't considered that.

Comment: although `fn(id1)` will return "could not find function fn" in any case (could be confusing since it would give the original value of `funname` ...)